# jQuery smooth scrolling to anchor after button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't get this to smoothly scroll down to the anchor for some reason. Can anybody see why?

This is the html:

```
<div id="onward">
    <a href="#xdroneslogan" class="btn">
        <i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i> Onward
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script>
    $("#onward a").click(function(){
      var onwardId = $(this).attr("href");
      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(onwardId).offset().top}, "slow");
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have tried to [google](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) first?

Answer (score 4):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/bguAG/1/

**JS:-**

```
$("#onward a").click(function () {
    var onwardId = $(this).attr("href");
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(onwardId).offset().top
    }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div id="xdroneslogan" style="height:1000px;background:red;"></div>
<div id="onward">
<a href="#xdroneslogan" class="btn"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white"></i> Onward</a>

</div>
```

Also make sure the `jQuery.fx.off` is set to false.

Comment: @user2475130 - Does this answer your question?